# In Javascript Why result of -'54'+30 is -24(type coercion in javascript)

Tags: javascript, operator-precedence, unary-operator

Why I am getting the result of `-'54'+30` expresion as **-24** however when I tried to remove the (minus)`-` from expression then It is just concatenation of string and gives `5430` as output.Can anyone explain about how is it working.

```js
console.log(-'54'+30)
console.log('54'+30)
```

Comment: `-` operator converts its operand to number, and the math is done. Without minus operator string concatenation is executed instead.

Comment: Easy to figure out try `console.log(typeof -'54')`

Comment: I already added console in my question

Comment: What is the result when you do `console.log('-54'+30)`? See how that also turns to a string? So what do you think the `-` in your 1st line actually is doing?

Comment: @Igor- I undestand console.log('-54'+30) is just string concatenation .I think answers are explained me well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because [unary negation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_negation) has a higher [operator precedance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) than addition.

Unary negation also converts its operand to a `Number` Per [ECMA Spec 2017](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-unary-minus-operator):

> The unary - operator **converts its operand to Number** type and then
>   negates it. Negating +0 produces -0, and negating -0 produces +0.

In the case of `-'54'+30` the steps are:

1. Evaluate the unary `-`
2. The right hand operand is a `String` so it is turned into a `Number`
3. The `+` is evaluated
4. The left hand operand is a `Number` due to step 2 so the `+` operation is addition instead of concatenation

Comment: what? even if you try +'54'+30 it will not concatenate. The operator converts them to number.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal right, that's what I'm saying.  The conversion happens before the concatenation happens.  Since the left hand operand is a Number, the `+` operator performs addition instead of concatenation.

Comment: operator precedence doesn't matter. remove first line which is misleading... you may get some hint looking at my answer.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal I disagree.  If unary negation had a lower precedence they would concatenate first.  Consider `-('54'+30)` vs `-'54'+30`.  The unary is what is doing the conversion, if it happened later then concatenation would occur.

Comment: -'54' will do type conversion but why it should be coerced if the other operand is still string? Your statement is right. but not in this scenario. In your last comment, you are stating which will be evaluated first. But I am not saying that. I'm saying why type conversion is required.

Answer (score 2):

The `-` operator is performing a type coercion. There is a common Javascript idiom for converting a string to a number type:

```
const n = +'60'
```

That makes `n` equal to `60` numerically, not just in the string form. This is the same deal, only you're using a negative operator which will invert the sign on the value and provide `-60`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `+` or `-` symbol will coerce its type. So, -'54'+30 will do math and return -24.

But, if you try like this:

```
-'54'+'30' // -5430
```

Then it will not type coerce since both '54' and '30' are string. And JavaScript will not force it to do math.

So, to coerce the type there should be different values like string + number can be type coerced where string will be coerced to number.

Useful links for how type coercion works?

- [Type conversion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes/Using_js-ctypes/Type_conversion)
- [Type conversion explained in medium](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/js-type-coercion-explained-27ba3d9a2839)
- [More about type conversion in Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion)

For full detail see [this chart](https://delapouite.com/ramblings/javascript-coercion-rules.html) for type coercion rule.

Comment: I had seen better explanation about type conversion rule in MDN but currently not able to find that one. :)